# Generating same random array each time

Tags: python, random-seed

Suppose we want to generate the same random number between 1 and 10 each time. Then when I run the following I get the same random number each time:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(30)
random.randint(1, 10)
9


random.seed(30)
random.randint(1, 10)
9
```

But if I want to generate the same random 4x4 matrix with numbers between 1 and 10 each time, I get different results:

```
random.seed(30)
np.random.randint(10, size=(4,4))
array([[8, 2, 6, 4],
   [3, 3, 3, 5],
   [6, 2, 6, 6],
   [8, 7, 1, 1]])


 random.seed(30)
 np.random.randint(10, size=(4,4))
 array([[9, 2, 1, 6],
   [4, 3, 3, 8],
   [1, 1, 6, 6],
   [0, 2, 3, 5]])
```

**Question.** How do I get the same array each time using  `random.seed()` ?

**Added.** I added the import statements.

Comment: before you run the second time, do you quit python first and then re-enter into python? If not, you should be getting the same results

Comment: Please show your imports. It looks like you're using *random* methods from two different modules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why random seed does not make results constant in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661426/why-random-seed-does-not-make-results-constant-in-python)

Comment: @PM77-1: added the import methods.

Comment: see my answer. hope it helps

Comment: I hope you can see the issue by yourself now.

Comment: @PM77-1: I see it now, sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to use `numpy.random.seed` and not `random.seed`.

Now, you mix 2 different modules i.e. `numpy` and `random`.

---

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(5):
    np.random.seed(30)
    print(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,4)))

[[5 5 4 7]
 [2 5 1 3]
 [9 7 7 1]
 [1 3 2 2]]
[[5 5 4 7]
 [2 5 1 3]
 [9 7 7 1]
 [1 3 2 2]]
[[5 5 4 7]
 [2 5 1 3]
 [9 7 7 1]
 [1 3 2 2]]
[[5 5 4 7]
 [2 5 1 3]
 [9 7 7 1]
 [1 3 2 2]]
[[5 5 4 7]
 [2 5 1 3]
 [9 7 7 1]
 [1 3 2 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the stupid question. Thats what sleep deprivation does.

Comment: glad that I could help. consider upvoting my answer if it helped.